# Typescript EventEmmiter обновление таблицы после удаления записи

Tags: ui, typescript, update

У меня есть вопрос. Как правильно в моем случае использовать EventEmmiter?

Мне надо удалить запись из таблицы и обновить ее. Но как я поняла методы вызываются одновременно, и обновление заканчивается до удаления.

```
 delete(car) {
        this._auto.deletecar(car)
            .subscribe(result => { this.cars= result}
            ,
            error => alert(error));

        this._auto.findcar(this.carsList)
            .subscribe(result => { this.carslist = result; }
            ,
            error => alert(error));
    }
```

Все работает, но корректное обновление таблицы происходит только если дебажить (методам хватает времени).

Как правильно запустить метод "обновить" именно после завершения метода удаления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант

```
deleteCar(car) {
    var self =this;
    this._auto.deletecar(car)
        .subscribe(result => { 
        self.cars = result;
        self.findCar();
    },
    error => {
      self.findCar();
      alert(error));
    }
}

findCar() {
    this._auto.findcar(this.carsList)
        .subscribe(result => { this.carslist = result; }
        ,
        error => alert(error));
}
```

Comment: Вообще перестало обновлять((

Comment: @Antatrix, а ошибки есть?

Comment: @KonstatninsOkhotnick Теперь просто пропускает findCar.  Вся суть в том чтобы запихнуть обновление в subscribe?

Comment: @Antatrix алерты с ошибками появлятся?

Comment: @KonstatninsOkhotnick да, но это связано с тем, что пытается обратиться к уже удаленному объекту (на методе deletecar)

Comment: ага, тоесть вам надо что бы findCar обновлялся при любом случае, если deleteCar в error попал то тоже отрабатывает findCar, так?

Comment: @KonstatninsOkhotnick получается что так)

Comment: отредактировал пример.  в error добавил вызов self.findCar();

Comment: хотя мне и не совсем понятно почему надо обновлять  this.carslist если ничего не удалилось

Comment: @KonstatninsOkhotnick спасибо большое, заработало))

Comment: @KonstatninsOkhotnick для самообразования... Что делает self? Просто когда я добавляла обновление в subscribe без него работало криво. Вызывет обновление только после удаления?

Comment: @Antatrix тут надо понимать, что такое контекст вызова. This возвращает ссылку на текущий класс, в начале функции deleteCar this указывает на текущий класс, а в подписчике (subscribe ), он меняет контекст, а  self = this - этим зафиксировали текущий котекст.

Comment: то есть через self можем обращаться к функциям текущего класса-контроллера.